# How do I use variables that are in my main file (main.cpp) in other files (foo.h, foo.cpp)?

Tags: c++, variables

How do I use variables that are in my main file (`main.cpp`) in other files (`foo.h`, `foo.cpp`)?
No code is really necessary but I'll post some to help clarify my question.

`main.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include<foo.h>

using namespace std;

int aa = 10;
int bb = 20;

Foo xyz;

int main() {
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    xyz.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

`foo.h`

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H


class Foo
{
    public:
        void doSomething() {
            int abc = aa + bb;
            cout<<"aa + bb = "<<abc<<endl;
        };
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

Comment: That’s a **really bad idea**. Don’t do this. Pass them as arguments instead.

Comment: Can you provide a link or give an example, please?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/2366 — The short answer is that having global variables makes it impossible to create small, self-contained composable solutions. But composing small, self-contained solutions is the *only way* to write complex programs because humans have small brains and can’t think of the whole program at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare a `main.h` file, declare your variable there and declare it later in the `main.cpp`. So you would have

`main.h`

```
extern int aa, bb;
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "main.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <foo.h>

using namespace std;

int aa = 10;
int bb = 20;

Foo xyz;

int main() {
    cout<<"Hello World"<<endl;
    xyz.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Then you can just include `main.h` and use `aa` and `bb`

Comment: *"and declare it later in the main.cpp"* -> *"and define it later in the main.cpp"*

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. But should I also include ``main.h`` in my main.cpp?

Comment: global variables are usually something that you should try to avoid. IMO this may be a working example but a very bad one.

Comment: @Default Yes, I agree very much. This is veeeery bad code, but the answer to this question. Please don't do that, pass variables as parameters and avoid global variables.

Comment: @JeromeReinländer then why don't you add that to your question?

Comment: @Default Strictly speaking, the answer I posted is the answer to the question, and my comment is a comment about the coding style. So I feel like everything is where it belongs.

Comment: Instead of `extern` can I have `Public`.

Comment: @ZakTheHat they're not the same things. `public` is for class members.

Comment: @ZakTheHat `extern` means you will define the variable... well, externally. `public` sets the visibility of a member. These are completely different concepts.

Comment: @ZakTheHat yes, it's a good idea to include `main.h` in your `main.cpp` because it can catch inadvertent mistakes that wouldn't otherwise get caught; e.g. if you declare `extern int aa;` in main.h but define it as `float aa = 1.234;` in main.cpp.

Comment: @Default Why is it a bad Idea to use this method?

Comment: @ZakTheHat global variables are hard to maintain. Depending on how you want to use your variable(s) there are other methods of letting `Foo` know of them. One example being for instance as parameters to `doSomething`

Comment: @ZakTheHat when I type "Why are g" into Google, it autocompletes it as "Why are global variables bad?" It is a question that has a lot of websites explaining why it is bad.

Comment: I'm getting errors saying: ``undefined reference to variableName``

Comment: @DodgyCodeException If you type "Why are g" into duckduckgo you would not get those results. Google has tailored it's experience to you. Instead of saying "just google it" you might want to suggest some specific question on stackoverflow or other resource.

Comment: @ZakTheHat you need to `#include "main.h"` in foo.cpp.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I'm getting errors in ``main.cpp`` and I also have ``#include "main.h"``

Comment: I just forgot to declare the variables in ``main.cpp`` as well as ``main.h``

Comment: Do I need to make the variables in ``main.cpp`` pointers to the one declared in ``main.h``?

Comment: @ZikTheHat No, that's not necessary. What you are doing in the `main.h` is similar to a forward declaration of a class. You basically say "There will be a variable named aa of type int, but I am not defining that here"